# jquery jtable not showing the results

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jquery-jtable

I am trying to show data in my jtable but it is just showing the number of rows in my table but not the data.
my jsp looks like

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>jtable integration</title>

<%-- JQuery --%>
<script src="<c:url value="/js/jquery-1.8.2.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js" />"></script>

<%-- Jtable --%>

<script src="<c:url value="/js/Utility.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/js/jTable/jquery.jtable.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/js/jTable/jquery.jtable.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/js/StudentJtable.js" />"></script>

<link href="<c:url value="/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="/js/jTable/Themes/Metro/blue/jtable.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
<h1>hi</h1>
    <div>
        <div id="StudentTableContainer" style="width: 99%;"></div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="myFunction()"></button>
    <label id="test">tttt</label>

</body>
</html>
```

studenttable.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
    //setup the jtable that will display the results
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Table of Student',
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting 
        paging: true, //Enable paging
        pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
        sorting: true, //Enable sorting
        actions: {
            listAction: 'datatable/getAllStudents',
        },
        fields: {
            ID: {
                title: 'iD',
                key: true,
                list: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false
            },
            NAME: {
                title: 'name',
                width: '50%'
            },
            AGE: {
                title: 'age',
                width: '30%'
            }

        }

    });
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');              

});
```

student model

```
package com.model;

import java.util.Date;

    public class Student {
         private Integer age;
           private String name;
           private Integer id;

           public void setAge(Integer age) {
              this.age = age;
           }
           public Integer getAge() {
              return age;
           }

        public void setName(String name) {
              this.name = name;
           }
           public String getName() {
              return name;
           }

           public void setId(Integer id) {
              this.id = id;
           }
           public Integer getId() {
              return id;
           }
    }
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "datatable/getAllStudents", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public JsonJtableStudentListResponse getAllExpenses(@RequestParam int jtStartIndex, @RequestParam int jtPageSize) {
        JsonJtableStudentListResponse jstr;
        int count= 0;
        List<Student> students= studentDaoImp.getStudents();
        count=students .size();
        jstr = new JsonJtableStudentListResponse("OK",students,count);
        return jstr;
        //return new JsonJtableResponse().ok(students);
    }
```

there are total 9 records in the table and my jtable i showing 9 rows but no data.

can somebody help me i am just learning this now. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i had done a silliest mistake possible.

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
    //setup the jtable that will display the results
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Table of Student',
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting 
        paging: true, //Enable paging
        pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
        sorting: true, //Enable sorting
        actions: {
            listAction: 'datatable/getAllStudents',
        },
        fields: {
            ID: {
                title: 'iD',
                key: true,
                list: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false
            },
            NAME: {
                title: 'name',
                width: '50%'
            },
            AGE: {
                title: 'age',
                width: '30%'
            }

        }

    });
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');              

});
```

i was using capitals in my js and small in my model table.